# Spotify API queue method returning 503 Service Unavailable error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, queue, spotify

I'm using Spotify developer API from a webapplication I'm developing in Ruby on Rails.
For that I'm using a gem called [rspotify](https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify). 
I modified it slightly in order to add the capability to queue a song which is offered by the Spotify API.
Here is the API documentation from Spotify Dev: 
https://developer.spotify.com/console/post-queue/

Here is the original piece of code from rspotify with all existing (and working) calls (like play a song):
https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify/blob/master/lib/rspotify/player.rb

And here is the piece of code I added:

```
def queue(device_id = nil, uri)
  url = "me/player/queue?uri=#{uri}"
  url = device_id.nil? ? url : "#{url}?device_id=#{device_id}"

  User.oauth_put(@user.id, url, {})
end
```

Unfortunately, all methods work but not this one. 
Here is an example of the call with the error I get (extract of a ruby call in the console):

```
> me = RSpotify::User.new(hash)
> player = RSpotify::Player.new(me)
> track = RSpotify::Track.search('Know')[0]
>
> player.play_track(track.uri)
 => nil
> player.queue(track.uri)
warning: Overriding "Content-Type" header "application/json" with "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" due to payload
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):82
RestClient::ServiceUnavailable (503 Service Unavailable)
```

Note that the call to method play_track works fine. Only the player.queue is a problem here.

I hope somebody can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved.

The issue was coming from the fact that a PUT method was used instead of a POST.
Here is the fixed code:

```
def queue(device_id = nil, uri)
  url = "me/player/queue?uri=#{uri}"
  url = device_id.nil? ? url : "#{url}&device_id=#{device_id}"
  User.oauth_post(@user.id, url, {})
end
```

Hope it will save some time to others